# How can I program a custom partial or sub view for a calculator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm building a basic calculator app. The calculator is already fully functional with basic features. The problem I'm having is I ran out of room on the screen to add other, more advanced features. Ideally what I would like to do is create some kind of subclass and view that slides up to to the bottom of the label (where the completed calculations are displayed),  when a button on the bottom of the screen is pressed. In other words, I want a view with more operators and computation options to slide up to the bottom of the label and I dont want this view to cover up any digits that are being displayed in the label. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  When your button is pressed, create your new view (with the extra functions), add it as a subview to self.view, and animate a change to it's frame, so that it's frame changes from below the visible view to just below your digits.

Like this:

```
-(void) buttonPressed {
 UIView *myNewView = << create your view >>
 myNewView.frame = CGRectMake(0,480, 320,200);  // or whatever your width and height are
    // 480 means it will be below the visible frame.
 [self.view addSubview: myNewView];
 float bottom_Y_of_digit_display = 100;// or wherever it is...

 [UIView beginAnimations:nil contenxt:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDelay: 0.0];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];  // one second.
 myNewView.frame = CGRectMake(0,bottom_y_of_digit_display, 320,200);
 [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to xcode and objective-c and I'm trying to wrap my head around this. This buttonPressed would be an action right? What I don't understand is the << create your view >>. I understand that your assigning it a pointer to UIView class. But I don't understand how to actually create a view through this action method.

Comment: Yes, in your button, specify that it calls that method when user taps it (touch up inside).  You need to create a new class that will be a subclass of UIView, and will contain all of your additional advanced features. Assume it's called "AdvancedView". Then you instantiate that class like this:  AdvancedView *myNewView = [[AdvancedView alloc] init];

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIAnimations to create an animation out of any changes to UIView properties. You can make your UIView hidden by settings its frame.origin.y to 480 and then change the rect and wrap it in a UIAnimation.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
CGRect newFrame = newSubView.frame;
newFrame.origin.y -= newSubView.frame.size.height;
newSubView.frame = newFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

**UPDATE**

If you are targeting iOS 4.0 and later then you should use the new UIAnimations interface.

```
UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0 options:options 
        animations:^(){
            CGRect newFrame = newSubView.frame;
            newFrame.origin.y -= newSubView.frame.size.height;
            newSubView.frame = newFrame;
        } 
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
           //Do something upon completion
        }];
```